# Animation works only on first button click

Tags: android, android-animation

I was wondering how to handle animations correctly. The code below is working fine but the animation starts only for the first click. It does not work again after the first click.

Layout:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/play"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@drawable/speaker" />
```

Animation File 'anim.xml':

```
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:oneshot="true" >
<item
android:drawable="@drawable/choose12"
android:duration="100"/>
<item
android:drawable="@drawable/choose12_1"
android:duration="100"/>
<item
android:drawable="@drawable/choose12_2"
android:duration="100"/>
<item
android:drawable="@drawable/choose12"
android:duration="100"/>
</animation-list>
```

Activity:

```
final Button speakButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.play);
    speakButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String words = getResources().getString(R.string.select_age);
            speakWords(words);
            speakButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.anim.xml);
            AnimationDrawable AppNameAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) speakButton.getBackground();
            AppNameAnimation.start();
        }
    });
```

In the code above the animation is working fine only for the first click, but it won't start at the second (or third, or Nth) click.

How can I start the animation each time the button is clicked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following way... Maybe it is because you already set the `BackgroundResource` to `R.drawable.anim.xml`. So again this line could not be compiled by the compiler. I think `AnimationDrawable` would not start for the same resource. If you change it dynamically you can get it.

```
final Button speakButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.play);
    speakButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String words = getResources().getString(R.string.select_age);
            speakWords(words);
            speakButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.anim.xml);
            AnimationDrawable AppNameAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) speakButton.getBackground();
            AppNameAnimation.start();

            speakButton.post(new Runnable() {

               @Override
               public void run() {

                  if(AppNameAnimation.getCurrent() != AppNameAnimation.getFrame(AppNameAnimation.getNumberOfFrames() - 1))
                  {
                     speakButton.post(this);
                  }else
                  {
                     speakButton.removeCallbacks(this);
                     speakButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.speaker);
                  }

               }
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: Hi Gunaselan, You code is working very very well to my app. Again thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem.

I fixed it by calling stop on the animation first if I had already played it

```
           mAnimationDrawable.stop();
           mImageView.setImageDrawable(mAnimationDrawable);
           mAnimationDrawable.start();
```